# Which values can be random in Pollard's factorization algorithm and are there any criteria for selecting them?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

In the paper [An Improved Monte Carlo Factorization Algorithm](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb051i.pdf) an algorithm is given for factoring numbers. Some values that are used are random. I'm wondering how such values should be chosen? Is truly uniform random the best or are some values better than others?

[image: screen shot of algorithm]

To my understanding $x_o$ and $m$ can be assigned the initial value randomly  from the range $[1, N-1]$ where $N$ is the input number. Also the function $f(x)=x^2+1$ is usually chosen but +1 can be random too. Is there any range?

Is there any other considerations? For example if the algorithm fails on $x_o=m=1$ would it be better to change one at a time or all of them?

Also does anyone have insight on what the variable $m$ actually represents?

Comment: As far as I know, little is known which polynomial will give a good chance to find a factor. It seems that it is a matter of luck whether we find a factor soon, or whether we find a factor at all.